# change df where the years at date is equal to 2020?

Tags: dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a Df with column date, I tried to search in this column where the years is 2020 and add to the date in the same point 31 days for example the df.date[1] = 10.12.2020 so this rows will be with the new data 10.1.2021

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for, if I'm understanding correctly:

```py
import datetime
import pandas as pd

# Create a dummy dataframe
date_range = pd.date_range(datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1), datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1))
test = pd.DataFrame({"date": date_range})

test
```

```
          date
0   2020-01-01
1   2020-01-02
2   2020-01-03
3   2020-01-04
4   2020-01-05
..         ...
727 2021-12-28
728 2021-12-29
729 2021-12-30
730 2021-12-31
731 2022-01-01
```

For each value, find if the year is 2020, and if so then add 31 days to the date:

```py
test['norm_date'] = test['date'].where(test['date'].dt.year != 2020, test['date'].dt.date.add(datetime.timedelta(days=31)))

test
```

```
          date  norm_date
0   2020-01-01 2020-02-01
1   2020-01-02 2020-02-02
2   2020-01-03 2020-02-03
3   2020-01-04 2020-02-04
4   2020-01-05 2020-02-05
..         ...        ...
727 2021-12-28 2021-12-28
728 2021-12-29 2021-12-29
729 2021-12-30 2021-12-30
730 2021-12-31 2021-12-31
731 2022-01-01 2022-01-01
```